# Cheap high-voltage low-current source

Tags: dc-dc-converter, high-voltage, boost

I'm looking to make a high voltage supply for some geiger-mueller tubes (the ubiquitous sbm-20 russian surplus tubes that everyone uses).  these don't require much current at all, so creating high voltage shouldn't be too tricky.

I'm using a 12 volt source, and I'd really like there to be some way to fine tune the voltage (either by setting a duty cycle, or a current set resistor, or something similar).  I'd also like it to be as cheap as possible (meaning probably a preference for discrete components over ICs) while being reasonably sized (say, the size of a clamshell phone).

It seems that a reasonable way to approach this would be to create a two-stage converter: a boost converter to get me up to, say, 48VDC, followed by a series of voltage doublers until I get to 500 - 700 VDC.

This two-phase approach allows me to fine tune the voltage relatively easily, and I should be able to get away with using cheap discrete components.

My questions are:

1. Is this a reasonable approach? Are there simpler ways to create a similar, charge-pump style voltage supply? I'd really like to have the simplest circuit I can while maintaining some semblance of tunability and stability.
2. If so, how would I couple the boost converter to a voltage doubler?  Do I need a transformer? Can I just use the diode and capacitor as the first diode/capacitor pair in the ladder? Do I need a second FET to switch the boost converter's load capacitor into the voltage ladder?

Any schematics or similar would be extremely helpful.

Comment: You would couple them exactly the same way you started the boost converter: an astable multivibrator.

Comment: This project in a local electronics mag a while back might give you a few ideas: http://www.jaycar.com.au/images_uploaded/geigercounterSC1995.pdf

Comment: related http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31833/3v-to-500v-dc-converter

Comment: Rather than "voltage doubler" you want a "Cockcroft-Walton Voltage Multiplier", but magnetics (a transformer in particular, since it's hard to get > 10:1 from an inductor) make for a simpler circuit.

Answer (score 3):

Just addressing the 'cheap' aspect, have you considered re-purposing the circuit from a relatively cheap COTS electric flyswatter.

Not exactly a good way to learn how it was designed, but it might get you there quick and dirty.   You might even need to use a voltage divider to bring the voltage back down

Answer (score 2):

I guess Maxim are a trusted source of designs and this probably does what you want: -

[image]

The design was found [here](http://www.maximintegrated.com/app-notes/index.mvp/id/3757)

Below is another common design I've seen: -

[image]

It came from [here](http://www.techlib.com/science/geiger.html)

Answer (score 0):

A flyback came to mind as something to consider. Something like the following:

[Dr. David Prutchi's hacked flyback](http://www.diyphysics.com/2013/05/08/original-source-for-flyback-driver-hack/)
[Dr. David Prutchi's flyback driver](http://www.diyphysics.com/2012/02/10/universal-resonant-transformer-driver-high-voltage-flyback-driver/)

Wind a smaller, more suitable flyback transformer by hand and use a long series chain of NE-2's for regulation on the secondary. It's been many years, but this is close to what I did for my hand-held, battery-powered Geiger counter then.

The above links are actually used to feed a 250kV system used for physics experiments discussed at:

[Dr. David Prutchi's 250kV Cockcroft-Walton](http://www.diyphysics.com/2012/02/09/d-i-y-250-kv-high-voltage-dc-power-supply-with-neat-trick-for-switching-polarity/)

But you don't need that.