# 500v generation with 24V

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, high-voltage

I want to generate 500V @100mA from a source of 24V @2.4A. My question is that would it be possible to maintain this current? Any clues please.

Comment: You may find some helpful information in this similar thread: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/31833/3v-to-500v-dc-converter

Comment: Both source and output are DC? Or AC? Or one AC and one DC? It helps to know.

Comment: Check your power ratings.  500V at 100mA is 50W out.  24 V at 2.4A is 57.6 W in.  You'll need an efficiency of near 90%.  Might be difficult to reach.

Comment: Both are DC power.

Comment: Did you try Texas Instruments WEBENCH to check if 90% is achievable with common components?

Comment: Not yet. I'll check it.